# Grease pencil strokes disappear in surface mode in Blender 2.8

Tags: grease-pencil

I'm learning grease pencil in Blender 2.8, hope you can help with a small frustrating issue:

When the stroke placement mode is set to 'surface' for drawing directly on a mesh, only the current stroke is visible as it is being made. Any previous strokes drawn on the surface disappear while a new stroke is drawn, and then reappear as soon as the current stroke is stopped. This makes it quite hard to draw.

[image]

I've seen videos of grease pencil 2.8 being used on a surface without this behavior, but I can't find any setting to alter it. If anyone can help (new to Blender) be very much appreciated.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I just recently experienced the same problem!

Maybe a solution to your problem:
In the "stroke placement" dropdown if you select "surface" there is also an option for an offset.
This works good.
However I found out that the offset to the projected surface as well as the thickness of the Gpencil is relative to the viewing distance to the object.

There should be an option for relative to object and relative to screenspace if you have placement on surface selected. 
Where can we report this? I don't know how I can get in touch with devs...

Anyways, I hope that helped!